# designing database for storing unavailable dates in a room booking app

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-design

I am working on a `room booking` application. I am using `rails 5` and `postgres`. The model goes like this.

A `Hotel` `has_many` `room_types`

`RoomTypes` table will look like this

```
RoomTypes

id: 1

name: "a specific room"

no_of_rooms_of_this_type: 5
```

The Hotel owner can mark a day as unavailable. So I will save each unavailable date as individual records.
 **Option 1**

I can think is to create a seperate table for each unavailable date.Is it the best approach? If thats the case I structure room like this

```
UnAvailabiltyTable

id: 1

room_id: 1

unavailable_day: Date
```

As a room has many different rooms of same kind `:no_of_rooms_of_this_type` and each will have its own availability I will endup creating multiple records with the same room_id. Is that ok??

**Option 2(not sure how efficient this is)**

Store the unavailable values as a jsonb column on each room

Could someone shed some light into this topic?

Comment: Have you considered making a Reservation model that `belongs_to` room and has a `start` datetime and `stop` datetime and whatever other information it needs?

Comment: @Okomikeruko that method works for booked rooms.. But am looking for a way the room owner can mark some dates as unavailable

Comment: Are these recurring dates?

Comment: no.its not recurring..Its a marketplace app. So planning to give the owners the option to set unavailable dates. I am planning to show  a jquery calender so that they can choose the dates thats unavailable.. But how to structure this info with my backend is what am struggling with...

Answer (score 0):

i don't see very clear your model but I think it should be like this:

```
Hotel has_many rooms
Room has_and_belongs_to_many bookings
Booking has_and_belongs_to_many rooms
```

`room_type` will be simply a `Room` attribute. This could vary depending on your needs, though.

Also `start_date` and `end_date` for Booking. You can add a validation for rooms and dates.

This way you'll be able to join rooms and bookings where type = 'whatever' and also create new bookings for a room. I don't see the need for more complexity.

Comment: sorry if the question is not very clear and thinks you got the question wrong as the method suggested by you will work for rooms booked. I am looking for the option for the room owner to mark one or more dates as unavailable on a calender. They can also mark multiple dates as unavailable using a jquery calender or so. but I cant figure out a solid way to save these dates in database.

Comment: I think it should work the same. Just change `Booking` by any other word you think that will fit better.